# ManyToMany Jpa Audtiting

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Lets assume

Enity Order

```
UUID id;
...

LocalDateTime createdAt;

@CreatedBy
UUID createdBy;
LocalDateTime updatedAt;

@LastModyfiedBy
UUID updatedBy;

@PrePersist
void onCreate() {
    this.createdAt = LocalDateTime.now();
}

@PreUpdate
void onUpdate() {
    this.updatedAt = LocalDateTime.now();
}

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "product_orders",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "id",
                    referencedColumnName = "product_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "order_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "id")
)
private Set<Oders> Orders;
```

Is it possbile to Audit the join Column in a manyToMany relationship using spring data jpa ?

In the product_oders table I have a column 'createdAt'and I'm struggeling with finding a solution how to audit this column.

Comment: By audit you mean track who has made changes to this relation? i.e. which user added/removed a product from an order?

Comment: Yes using somehow @PrePersist

Comment: The orders entity is `@Audited` as well?

Comment: Yes, the question is how to audit product_oders

Comment: I think you should/could model the Many-to-Many relation using a dedicated entity that is @Audited as well. Like it is done in this example to add additional attributes to the jointable https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-in-join-table-example

Comment: @Dpr Thank you . I used this as part of an template changed the ManyToMany as ManyToOne with an compositeKey.